# Why my global varibale do not override after post request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just need that me test object equill new data, but after override it in async function  but it still old adter whenGET request

```
var fcrForm = {
 employees:[]
};
$httpBackend.whenGET('http://localhost:3001/forms').respond(200, fcrForm);
$httpBackend.whenPUT('http://localhost:3001/forms').respond(function (method, url, data) {

    fcrForm = JSON.parse(data)
    return [200, fcrForm, {}]
});
```

Comment: You print the console message before the async function is executed. The variable will be updated correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix this using promise.then

```
const lol = async()=> {
const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
const res = await data.json()
test = res;
  return res;
}

lol().then(function(res) {
  console.log("test: " + test);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

the console.log(test) will execute before the

```
test = res
```

assignment will occur.

You need to await the lol call since it's an async function (making an async network call).

```
await lol()
```

This is part of the event loop in JS.

I recommend to read more about it here:

https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-event-loop-and-the-rise-of-async-programming-5-ways-to-better-coding-with-2f077c4438b5

Comment: awaiting on every step is not the way javascript should be implemented

Comment: this is not what i said. but the function lol is async, hence it needs to be awaited.